# Prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ containing another ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am preparing for my algebra exam, and I am stuck with this problem:

> Find all maximal and prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ containing the ideal $\mathbb{I}=(55,x^2+4,y).$

What is the general method for this type of problem? Or do we need to resort to some ad-hoc method here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: They correspond to maximal and prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(55,x^2+4,y)$.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb Z[x,y]/\mathbb I$ is a finite ring, so any maximal ideal containing $\mathbb I$ has quotient a finite field. What can be the characteristic of that field be?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I guess the characteristic can only be 5&11, is that right? Also, is it true that prime=maximal in this problem?

Comment: If $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal, then $R/\mathfrak p$ is an integral domain. Any finite integral domain is a field. So…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximal/prime ideals containing $I$ correspond precisely to the maximal/prime ideals of the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[x,y]/I$. This quotient is finite,  and hence it has only finitely many maximal/prime ideals.

Of course a maximal/prime ideal that contains $55$ must contain either $5$ or $11$, but not both. So you could also look at the two quotients by the ideals $I_1=(5,x^2+4,y)$ and $I_2=(11,x^2+4,y)$ separately, where
$$\Bbb{Z}[x,y]/I_1\cong\Bbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+4)
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\Bbb{Z}[x,y]/I_2\cong\Bbb{F}_{11}[x]/(x^2+4).$$
Can you determine the maximal/prime ideals of these two finite rings?